# JBatch: Disable Job logging to JobRepository in Glassfish / Payara

Tags: java-ee-7, glassfish-4.1, payara, jbatch

We are working with JBatch to execute a huge amount of jobs. We would like to disable the logging of the job execution to the JobRepository database in some circumstances, in best case on job level.
I haven't find any possibility to disable this logging in Glassfish /Payara Server, neither on job level nor entirely.
Did I miss anything or is this in general not possible?